# I have two questions about the code below

Tags: c++, string, compiler-warnings, c-strings

Running this code in VS2010, I get the warnings shown below, but the C-strings "f()" and "g()" are output on the console.

Question 1: Why does f() generates the warning and g() doesn't? Aren't string literals maintained in static memory until the program ends ?

Question 2: When I comment out the call to h() in main() the code crashes. Why the different behavior?

```
#include<iostream>

const char* const& f()
{
   return "f()";            //  warning C4172: returning address of local variable or temporary
}

const char* g()
{
    return "g()";           //  no warning
}

const std::string& h()
{
    return "h()";           //  warning C4172:
}

int main()
{
    std::cout << f() << '\n';
    std::cout << g() << '\n';
//  std::cout << h().c_str() << '\n';       //  comment out and program crashes
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You are returning a *reference* to a value that you only use locally. This is undefined behavior. What you probably want is to just return a char pointer, or a `std::string`, not a char pointer reference or a `std::string&`.

The fact that you happen to see `f()` printed out is just the luck of the draw. It is still undefined behavior, and can't be counted on.

Answer (score 2):

**f() produces undefined behaviour**. Undefined behaviour keeps your program in an invalid state which results in (pseudo-random) crashes.

It is undefined behaviour, because **you return a reference to a local variable**. After the function call the local variable will be destroyed, leaving your `char*` pointing to nowhere, really.

If you remove the reference, the value will be copied and we don't have a scope violation.

Comment: `After the function call the local variable will be destroyed, leaving your char* pointing to nowhere` But don't string literals stay alive till the end of the program?

Comment: @user1042389 The literal still exists, but the pointer to it is destroyed.

Comment: @Xymostech You mean the pointer (probably) associated with the reference?

Comment: Yes. There is a string literal somewhere in memory, your function creates a char pointer that points to it and returns a reference to it, but the pointer itself is destroyed when the function returns. So the reference points to random memory (it just happens that what it points to might have the value you want, but it also might not).

Comment: @Xymostech But how come VS2010 always return a valid address in f()? Thus, probably what you're saying is that other compilers might do it differently. Is that the idea?

Comment: @user1042389 As I already said, **it is undefined behaviour**. This also includes that it works.